# When (R)-2-bromopentane reacts with sodium methoxide, what is the major product?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I know that with a SN2 reaction mechanism this becomes (S)-2-methoxypentane, but with elimination this is trans-2-pentene. I know that elimination happens quickly when you apply heat. In this case we have a secondary alkyl halide so its possible to use SN2 or E2 due to methoxide being a strong nucleophile.

Comment: To be honest, I think it is very hard to decide as not enough information is provided. I think if the reaction temperature was given, it would help us find the answer much more easily. But yes, your deduction that it is either (S)-2-methoxypentane  or trans-2-pentene is sound.